# Is it better to use interface or an abstract class in this situation?

Tags: php, oop, interface, abstract

I want to know, If I have a shopping(eg the cart..payment process) class and I want to add the possibility to pay via paypal..is better to use an [**abstract class**<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/language.oop5.abstract) or an [**interface**<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/language.oop5.interfaces), eg:

```
Shopping implements Visa,Paypal
```

I guess that **interface** is the right answer, since the `Shopping` class will be recommended to be an **abstract** class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither.

`Shopping` (if you say its the main system, e.g. the shopping cart) should have a list of providers that implement/inherit `PaymentProcessor`. `Visa` and `PayPal` would implement/inherit from `PaymentProcessor`.

That way you can inject via some configuration what `PaymentProcessor`s are available. That way `Shopping` won't have to change if you add `MasterCard`.

Have a look at the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: So when it's best to use abstract and implement, can you give me to short examples

Comment: It depends - ask yourself, is there going to be any common logic?

Comment: I don't know, mabe because I don't understand so good design patterns, I will have to digg more on that.But for me is a common logic that Mastercard,Visa etc... to be an interface sincer I can implement them when I need them..eg..in a PaymentProcessor.

Answer (score 3):

Just based off of the name of your class I would guess you should use neither. The pattern you should look at is called composition. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition.

In short, your shopping class "uses a" payment processor, is isn't one itself (i.e. not an "is a" relationship)

I'd implement your shopping class to accept a payment processor either when it is instantiated or via a set method on the object.

You may also want to read up on [design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns), particularly from the Gang of Four.

Answer (score 1):

None of it, I would say. It would be better to have a Class for each paying method. I would use an abstract Class `Paying` (or similar) which implements aspects all paying methods use. Then you could write an Interface for every method (not really necessary) and the real implementation of every method that extends `Paying` (and might implement `Visa`).